# Animated Vector drawable animation not working properly

Tags: java, android

I want to run `AnimatedVectorDrawable` animation on infinite loop.

```
final AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat avd = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(this, R.drawable.avd_anim_happy);
    mImageView.setImageDrawable(avd);


    // animation on infinite loop
    avd.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Drawable drawable) {
            super.onAnimationStart(drawable);
            Log.e(TAG, "onAnimationStart() called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onAnimationEnd() called");
            avd.start();
        }
    });

    avd.start();
}
```

This works fine when I tested with **Nougat** device. But when I try to run this on **KitKat** device, callback is called but animation is not started again. There is no
"onAnimationStart() called" log message. But upon doing the following.

```
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onAnimationEnd() called");
            if (avd.isRunning()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "avd running!!");
                avd.stop();
            }
            avd.start();
        }
```

`onAnimationEnd()` and `onAnimationStart()` are getting called again and again. But for some reason animation just stopped after playing for one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue with old platforms, turns out i work around it by posting the start after the end event.

```
imageView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    avd.start();
                }
            });
```